# What does <==> mean in a LDAP query?

Tags: active-directory, ldap

We have several clients in our organization that are pounding the AD controllers with this strange LDAP query. Can someone explain what the purpose of this filter is? I don't know what the <==> does. We think it could be a mistake an update pushed out by Microsoft since it is coming from all different computers. Unsure though.

```
Client:53.220.59.79:56835|Filter: (member<==>CN=COMPVW7X13c3206,OU=Clients,OU=VDI,OU=AAAA,DC=company,DC=corpdir,DC=net)|07/09/2015 12:43:59
Client:53.220.128.58:50420|Filter: (member<==>CN=COMPD0007YQJWR1,OU=Clients,OU=TMP,OU=AAAA,DC=company,DC=corpdir,DC=net)|07/09/2015 12:43:56
Client:170.2.190.48:59515|Filter: (member<==>CN=COMPL0XE116753H,OU=Clients,OU=CVD,OU=AAAA,DC=company,DC=corpdir,DC=net)|07/09/2015 12:43:52
Client:53.220.56.146:60163|Filter: (member<==>CN=COMPVB642C60004,OU=Clients,OU=VDI,OU=AAAA,DC=company,DC=corpdir,DC=net)|07/09/2015 12:43:51
Client:53.220.59.3:59670|Filter: (member<==>CN=COMPV15W72A8042,OU=Clients,OU=VDI,OU=AAAA,DC=company,DC=corpdir,DC=net)|07/09/2015 12:43:49
Client:53.220.197.34:57626|Filter: (member<==>CN=COMPD0007Z41QN1,OU=Clients,OU=CVD,OU=AAAA,DC=company,DC=corpdir,DC=net)|07/09/2015 12:43:38
Client:53.220.59.163:49181|Filter: (member<==>CN=COMPV14W71B8147,OU=Clients,OU=VDI,OU=AAAA,DC=company,DC=corpdir,DC=net)|07/09/2015 12:43:18
Client:53.220.56.34:63054|Filter: (member<==>CN=COMPV14W72B6046,OU=Clients,OU=VDI,OU=AAAA,DC=company,DC=corpdir,DC=net)|07/09/2015 12:42:51
Client:53.220.198.83:52660|Filter: (member<==>CN=COMPD000J0Q1FQ1,OU=Clients,OU=CVD,OU=AAAA,DC=company,DC=corpdir,DC=net)|07/09/2015 12:42:50
```

Answer (score 0):

The query filters are looking strange.

IMHO `<==>` looks like **not** equal, but I've not seen before.

try to replace with:
`(!(member=CN=COMPVW7X13c3206,OU=Clients,... ) ... )`

`(! ... )` means negation of the following nested filters.

`(member=CN=COMPD0007YQJWR1,OU=Clients,...)` is the nested filter how will be negated.

http://ldapwiki.willeke.com/wiki/LDAP%20filters%20Syntax%20and%20Operators

Comment: Yeah that is the weird part. I know LDAP basics. I have never seen the <==> before and we were trying to figure out what application or service is generating these requests to our Active Directory Server.